# Mongoose find in nested Schema

Tags: javascript, mongodb, typescript, mongoose, subquery

I try to get all users with accountStatus.activated = false. But I just can not do it.

```
User.find({accountStatus: {activated: false}}) ...
```

**controller.ts**

```
import {User} from "../models/userModel";

public static getAllUsers(request, response, next): void {
    User.find().then(data => response.json(data)).catch(next);
}
```

**userModel**

```
const user:Schema = new Schema({
    name_first: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'First Name is required (name_first)']
    },
     accountStatus: {
        activated: {
            type: Boolean,
            default: false,
            required: true
        },
     }
});

export const User: Model = model("User", user);
```

please Help me D:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use dot notation:

```
User.find({'accountStatus.activated': false})
```